# How to get url from JSON text

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

Wondering if it is possible to get url's from the text, wich I parse from JSON. For example I have some JSON object which is in the JSON array and called "text". This "text" contains strings and images (url's) like a `img src=\u0022http:\/\/www.dostup1.ru\/netcat_files\/Image\/2014\/08\/04\/dzd-2.jpg`
but "img" or "src" are not in quotation marks so how can I get them and then parse this images to show?

```
item.setContent(post.getString("text"));
```

This is how I parse text and when it loads, it show me text with strange green rectangles instead of images (because of method doesn't know about how to parse image from url which just is in the text)

Comment: you just want the url from the string?? try to print the `post.getString("text")` in the console and see the result

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin, yep! I did that and now I get the string with `HTML` code <img src=""> how can I get an URL between the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that you have this piece of String from the result of your JSON.

```
<img src="http:\/\/www.dostup1.ru\/netcat_files\/Image\/2014\/08\/04\/dzd-2.jpg">
```

Then you just need to use the `split` method of the `String` class to extract the url between qoutes.

**sample:**

This is just a sample java program that split the URL from the `JSON` response you got

```
String s = "<img src=\"http://www.dostup1.ru/netcat_files/Image/2014/08/04/dzd-2.jpg\">";
String [] result = s.split("\"");
System.out.println(result[1]);
```

**result:**

```
http://www.dostup1.ru/netcat_files/Image/2014/08/04/dzd-2.jpg
```

Comment: But I got the String such as `<img src="http://www.dostup1.ru/netcat_files/Image/2014/08/04/dzd-5.jpg" alt="" width="403" height="538" />`